# Easiest way to manage JPA/Hibernate transactions in swing app

Tags: swing, hibernate, jpa

I have this java swing app with one thread, one database connection.
Anytime the user saves or edits something a have to write something like this:

```
private void buttonClickedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    EntityManager em = sessionFactory.openSession();
    EntityTransaction et = null;
    try {
        et = em.getTransaction();
        et.begin();

        // save, merge, update ...

        et.commit();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException pe) {
        if(et != null) et.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        if(em != null) em.close();
    }
}
```

I see in some tutorials  references to transactions managed by the container or something like that for web apps. What about desktop? Am I missing something here? Do I really need to write all this transaction code every time?

Comment: You could create something like a DAO aka Repository in domain driven design DDD that handles the transactions for you.

Comment: You mean move the code to another location? If it is the same code I'm still writing too much.

Answer (score 0):

A DAO could look like:

```
public class BaseDao {

    protected EntityManager em;

    public BaseDao() {
        EntityMangerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityMangerFactory("<your PU>");
        em = emf.createEntityMangerFactory();
    }

    public <E> E find(Class<E> clazz, Serializable id) {
        return em.find(clazz, id);
    }

    public <E> E getReference(Class<E> clazz, Serializable id) {
        return em.getReference(clazz, id);
    }

    public void persist(Object entity) {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        em.persist(entity);

        transaction.commit();
    }

... and any other methods of the EntityManager.
```

Comment: Your persist method with all the transaction stuff is what I'm trying to avoid. Maybe it's not possible

Comment: Then you should transfer all the code that should run in one transaction in an own layer like a service layer and call that code from your event handling. It's all about code design and separation of concern. Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx

Comment: What about transaction.rollback() in the persist() method? As I know the em.persist() method throws some unchecked exceptions, so I have to add a catch(Exception e), doing the rollback there and throw a DaoException? Other posiibilites?